# What happen with eigenvalues when we change the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example to show that the eigenvalues change when we subtract multiple of a line fron another line. Give an explanation why if $0$ is one of the eigenvalues, then it doesn't change.

I gave an example in the first part of the exercise but I don't know how to explain the second part. Any thoughts?

Comment: The operation [is equivalent to multiply by certain matrix with non-zero determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-addition_transformations). Zero is an eigenvalue when the determinant is zero. So, when you multiply by the matrix with non-zero determinant, then you still get a matrix with determinant zero.

Comment: @user647486 Oh I got it, thanks a lot!